# How to get index of searched element in array and update the last element in that line Python

Tags: python, arrays, readfile

```
eg. of file:
v   x    y  z    
a   b    c   d
e   f    g   h
```

I have read file into array

```
with open(org_file, 'r') as file :
         filedata = file.readlines()
```

Now I want to search and see if the first 3 elements in the line matches if so I want to update the last element

```
 for line in filedata :
    # Strips the newline character
              if first_element in line and second_element in line and third_element in line:
                 print first_element +"   "+ second_element + "  "  + third_element+ "  "
```

Here I am getting unsure how to update the 4th element. As I am not sure the index number of 4th element.The search is displaying the presence of the element but not giving the index where it is present.

Comment: `line_list = line.split()`, the 4th element is `line_list[3]`

Comment: Thanks. that worked I am getting the last value i.e 4th value.. How do I update it back in the file

Comment: Write new `lines` into a new file, then rename it and replace original file.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last element using [-1] no matter the length of the array. You can also access the fourth element in your array which is the last by using [3] because any python array has Zero-based array indexing.
So:

array[0] = first element

array[1] = second element

and so on

```
with open(org_file, 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.readlines()

for line in filedata:
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0] == line[1] and line[1] == line[2]:
        line[-1] = 'change the last element to whatever you want'
        text = " ".join(line)
        print(text)
```

the .join() function joins each element in an iterable (list or tuple) in one string instead of typing this  `print first_element +"   "+ second_element + "  "  + third_element+ "  "+fourth_element`. You can find an explanation for this function on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20String%20join%20%28%29%20Method%201%20Definition%20and,returned%20values%20are%20the%20keys%2C%20not%20the%20values.).